# Oracle/OCI libraries could not be loaded: RubyGem version error: ruby-oci8(1.0.7 not >= 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Clearly 1.0.7 is greater than 0

came in and tried to used my Rails app and I get this.  worked yesterday.

So I removed the ruby-oci8 1.0.7 gem and reinstalled it. same problem.

Tried a different dev branch of my app and same problem.

I am running RoR on a Windows installation and looking for any ideas as to what might have gotten corrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things, reinstalling orcale, instantclient, ruby-oci8 various versions with no new results, this finally worked.

I copied my Ruby directory as a backup.
Installed Ruby1.8.7 over the existing directory.
All the gems stayed installed.
Ran my application and no ruby-oci8 (1.0.7 >= 0) errors.

So something in my Ruby install was corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem year ago. Since that i didn't work with rails and oracle, but at that times i found that not all versions work together. Mayne, something had changed.
But why are you using so old oci gem? I had 2.0.4 version of ruby - oci8 and activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.3.1  - it worked properly, as far as i remember

Comment: I have to use this version of the gem because I am in an enterprise environment and can not change the version of the gem on my local dev machine.